# Slow rendering process in Three.js output

Tags: javascript, three.js, render, blender, gltf

I have created a 3d model from Autodesk 3D max and exported a Object file from it. Than I imported that in Blender and installed a GLTF plugin in it. Than after doing some changes I exported a GLTF file with a bin file from it and provided that to some other person who was working on post processing. But don't know why the render time is too slow? please help me out.

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the right place for this question. Here, you can ask about Specific programming problems, Software algorithms, Coding techniques, Software development tools.

Answer (score -2):

Log renderer.info In the threejs app. You want ~1 million triangles and ~500 drawcalls.

Comment: It's the most common performance bottleneck. You call `load( file )` and the (external) three.js loader, creates a three.js data structure that wrecks your rendering pipeline. The pipeline is best summed up in the amount of vertices being processed and the amount of draw calls being issued. Logging `renderer.info` is the basic first step to figuring out what may be impacting your performance. It's a pretty good generic answer to a generic question with no actual information provided.